# issues with installing packages after updating R and RStudio to the latest versions

Tags: r

I just updated R and RStudio to latest versions. Then i get a warning that a lot of packages have not been installed. I tried downloading `sf`, but the installation fails. I scoured google for answers/solutions/workarounds, but nothing seems to work for me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
> install.packages("sf")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/sf_1.0-7.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 88883512 bytes (84.8 MB)
========
downloaded 15.1 MB

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 15863106 != reported length 88883512
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/sf_1.0-7.tgz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/sf_1.0-7.tgz' failed
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘sf’ failed
```

I also tried installing `terra`, installation failed too. I followed suggestions to remove the package from the library (but does not exist), re-open a clean version of RStudio and attempt to re-install. With same result.

```
> install.packages("terra")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is
  later:
      binary source needs_compilation
terra 1.5-21 1.5-34              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source package ‘terra’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/terra_1.5-34.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 667829 bytes (652 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 652 KB

* installing *source* package ‘terra’ ...
** package ‘terra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure: CC: clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13
configure: CXX: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/terra’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/cb/gj9pv0x5429dvzrnbqk9rlw40000gn/T/RtmpFQzKug/downloaded_packages’
```

Trying to install `rgdal` also gives the same issue:

```
> install.packages("rgdal")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is
  later:
      binary source needs_compilation
rgdal 1.5-30 1.5-32              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source package ‘rgdal’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgdal_1.5-32.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4469369 bytes (4.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure: R_HOME: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
configure: CC: clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13
configure: CXX: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++14
configure: CFLAGS: -Wall -g -O2
configure: CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/include
configure: CXXFLAGS: -Wall -g -O2
configure: LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib
configure: LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib
configure: CXX11 is: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13, CXX11STD is: -std=gnu++11
configure: CXX is: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11
configure: C++11 support available
configure: rgdal: 1.5-32
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
svnversion: error: Failed to locate 'svnversion'.
svnversion: error: The subversion command line tools are no longer provided by Xcode.
configure: svn revision: 1176
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/cb/gj9pv0x5429dvzrnbqk9rlw40000gn/T/RtmpFQzKug/downloaded_packages’
```

I went to CRAN, downloaded the .tgz file, installed it (succesfully? didn't return a warning/error). I then loaded the library but it failed:

```
> install.packages("~/Desktop/rgdal_1.5-32.tgz", repos = NULL, type = .Platform$pkgType)
> library("rgdal")
Loading required package: sp
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgdal’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Below my session info

```
My session info:
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
 os       macOS Catalina 10.15.7
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  en_US.UTF-8
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8
 tz       America/Los_Angeles
 date     2022-06-17
 rstudio  2022.02.3+492 Prairie Trillium (desktop)
 pandoc   NA

─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 brio          1.1.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 cachem        1.0.6   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 callr         3.7.0   2021-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 colorspace    2.0-3   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 cowplot       1.1.1   2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 crayon        1.5.1   2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 DBI           1.1.2   2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 desc          1.4.1   2022-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 devtools    * 2.4.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 dplyr         1.0.9   2022-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 generics      0.1.2   2022-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 ggplot2       3.3.6   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 lattice       0.20-45 2021-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 memoise       2.0.1   2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 pillar        1.7.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 pkgbuild      1.3.1   2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 pkgload       1.2.4   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 processx      3.6.1   2022-06-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 ps            1.7.0   2022-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 purrr         0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 Rcpp          1.0.8.3 2022-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 remotes       2.4.2   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 rgeos         0.5-9   2021-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 rprojroot     2.0.3   2022-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 scales        1.2.0   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 sp            1.5-0   2022-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 testthat      3.1.4   2022-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 tibble        3.1.7   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 tidyselect    1.1.2   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 usethis     * 2.1.6   2022-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 vctrs         0.4.1   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)

 [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library
```

Comment: Ok, sf succesfully downloaded after setting options(timeout = 600) following Edzer's recommendation.

Comment: Also, it will probably work if you do not try to install from source, use the binary packages instead. And if you are trouble-shooting, you should work in a clean session, not with all these other packages loaded.